# How can I check if swap is active from the command line?

Tags: swap

How can I check if swap is active, and which swap devices are set up, on the command line?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

in linux, you can use

- `cat /proc/meminfo` to see total swap, and free swap  (all linux)
- `cat /proc/swaps` to see which swap devices are being used  (all linux)
- `swapon -s` to see swap devices and sizes (where swapon is installed)
- `vmstat` for current virtual memory statistics

in Mac OS X, you can use

- `vm_stat` to see information about virtual memory (swap)
- `ls -lh /private/var/vm/swapfile*` to see how many swap files are being used.

in Solaris, you can use

- `swap -l` to see swap devices/files, and their sizes
- `swap -s` to see total swap size, used & free
- `vmstat` to see virtual memory statistics

On some systems, "virtual memory" refers only to disk-backed memory devices, and on other systems, like Solaris, Virtual Memory can refer to any user process address space, including tmpfs filesystems (like /tmp) and shared memory space.

Comment: Also, `free` should tell you how much swap is available to your system.

Comment: `cat /proc/meminfo` should be `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Swap`

Comment: use `free -h` for human readable sizes.

Comment: The swapon -s (--summary) seems to be deprecated at least in util-linux 2.37.2.  The swapon --show shows similar information.

Answer (score 36):

**`swapon --show`**

This is a bit better than `swapon -s` as it provides human friendly size units. E.g. if swap is active you could see:

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE   USED PRIO
/dev/dm-1 partition 7.5G 563.8M   -2
```

If `swap` is not active, it doesn't show anything.

`man swap` says:

> -s, --summary
>
> Display swap usage summary by device.  Equivalent to "cat /proc/swaps".  This output format is DEPRECATED in favour of --show that provides better control on output data.
>
> --show[=column...]
>
> Display a definable table of swap areas.  See the --help > output for a list of available columns.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04, util-linux 2.31.1.

Answer (score 34):

Try `swapon -s` for a list of current swap devices and other relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

With Linux you can use the `top` command to see if the swap is *active* or not, in which you can see something like `kswapd0`. The `top` command provides a dynamic real-time view of a running system, thus you should see the swap there.

If you don't see it there, it's more then likely it isn't working. to restart it or enable it, you can use this command: `sudo swapon --all --verbose` ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq))

Then by running the `top`command again you should see it.