# How to add 100MB of swap space as a logical volume in CentOS?

Tags: linux, fstab, swap

I need to add 100MB of swap space to my machine. I was trying to use a logical volume.

```
# lvcreate –name lv_swap2 –size 100M vg
# mkswap /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# swapon /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# vi /etc/fstab
/dev/vg/lv_swap2 swap defaults 0 0
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote everything right but missed something here: **swap** swap defaults

```
# lvcreate –name lv_swap2 –size 100M vg
# mkswap /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# swapon /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# vi /etc/fstab
/dev/vg/lv_swap2 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Now it should work.

Comment: @genghis, i would recommend editing fstab, then use `swapon -a`. Finally, check if swap is active (<http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23072/16640>), so everything is fine on reboot.